# I have developed an app and its not running on my phone

Tags: android

This is the mainfest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yash.pers.onlinepost"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="yash.pers.onlinepost.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Y(Gingerbread) and when I install the APK it says Application not installed. Please help me solve this problem. This is the first app I've developed for android.

Comment: can you give some further information about your error message? Where does it say "Application not installed" ?

Comment: I downloaded the file from Gmail and installed it, so it says "Application not installed" after the process

Comment: I had to sign my application to be able to install it from an apk. If you're using Eclipse it's easy to sign, it's under android tools.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try, because I haven't signed my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, your phone have to **allow Unkown sources**. Search for `android allow unknown sources` in google, you'll see a lot of threads explaining that.

---

Try to **uninstall previously installed version** of the same application. The signature might differ..

---

Finally, yes @dutt is right, you have to **sign your application** to be able to install it in a device.

Comment: Yeah, I had already checked the "allow unknown sources" option. 
The problem was that I hadn't signed the application. Thanks a lot, now its running :)